# Qt Перегрузка оператора = для структуры

Tags: c++, qt, структуры, перегрузка-операторов

Не получается перегрузить оператор = для структуры.
Программа компилируется, но при выполнении прямого слияния крашится.

Структура:

```
struct Student
    {
        QString fio;
        int group;
        int ysp[5];

        Student& operator = (const Student &s)
        {
            fio = s.fio;
            group = s.group;
            ysp[0] = s.ysp[0];
            ysp[1] = s.ysp[1];
            ysp[2] = s.ysp[2];
            ysp[3] = s.ysp[3];
            ysp[4] = s.ysp[4];
            ysp[5] = s.ysp[5];
            return (*this);
        }
    };
```

Прямое слияние сортировка:

```
void MainWindow::Merge(Student *list_S, int left, int right)
{
    if (right == left) return;
    if (right - left == 1)
    {
        if (ui->Ascending->isChecked())
        {
            if (list_S[right].group < list_S[left].group) swap(list_S[right], list_S[left]);
        }
        if (ui->Descending->isChecked())
        {
            if (list_S[right].group > list_S[left].group) swap(list_S[right], list_S[left]);
        }
        return;
    }

    int m = (right + left) / 2;

    Merge(list_S,left, m);
    Merge(list_S,m + 1, right);

    Student buf[right];
    int xl = left;
    int xr = m + 1;
    int cur = 0;

    while (right - left + 1 != cur)
    {
        if (xl > m) buf[cur++] = list_S[xr++];
        else if (xr > right) buf[cur++] = list_S[xl++];

        else if (ui->Ascending->isChecked() && list_S[xl].group > list_S[xr].group)buf[cur++] = list_S[xr++];
        else if (ui->Descending->isChecked() && list_S[xl].group < list_S[xr].group)buf[cur++] = list_S[xr++];

        else buf[cur++] = list_S[xl++];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cur; i++) list_S[i + left] = buf[i];
}
```

Всё заработает если поправить в сортировке:

```
Student buf[right+1];
```

Comment: В каком конкретно месте крэшится?

Comment: Если крашится даже с оператором присвоения по умолчанию, то дело не в нем. Судя по косяку в вашем операторе присваивания, вы вполне можете лажать с индексами в list_S (например, в каком диапазоне у вас left и right?). Проверьте. В С++ индексация массива должна быть  от 0 до (размер массива -1).

Comment: да вроде так и стоит Merge(list_S,0,right-1)

Comment: Вылезает  сигнал: SIGSEGV назначение:segmentation fault начинается на : if (xl > m) buf[cur++] = list_S[xr++];

Comment: Проверьте, чему равны в этот момент cur и xr, и не вылезают ли они за границы соответствующих массивов.

Comment: когда cur > xr тогда крашит

Comment: ну а с границами массивов они как соотносятся? Попадают или нет?

Comment: cur вылетает за границу правой части.

Comment: Всё нашёл ошибку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строчка

```
ysp[5] = s.ysp[5];
```

лишняя. У вас в массиве 5 элементов, вот пять и копируйте (с 0 по 4), а в этой строчке вы гадите в память.

А на самом деле определять оператор присваивания в данном случае не нужно, так как оператор присваивания по умолчанию (синтезируемый компилятором автоматически) делает ровно то же самое.

Comment: может заменить **синтезируемый** на классическое **по умолчанию**

Comment: @tilin, перефразировал. Думаю пойдет.

Comment: Попробовал присваиванием по умолчанию все равно крашит.

Comment: @tilin "По умолчанию" - это вроде только к конструктору без параметров. А тут скорее автоматически генерируемый, но не конструктор по умолчанию?